# How to align button right in a flex container?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to float my button right and I hope someone can help me out here.

[image]

The yellow color shows the background of the div. The width of the div is set to 50%.

```css
.faq {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.outerDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.save {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <h2>New FAQ</h2>
  <input type="text" class="faq">
  <br>
  <button class="save" mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely, the styles on the `outerDiv` here(flexbox) override the floating styles on the button. You can use flexbox in the `.save` button to align right, using something like `align-self` or something. Also, please provide a full runnable example using Stackoverflow snippets or code sandbox.

Comment: I suggest that you abandon floats altogether. With the possible classic exception of getting text to wrap around an image there's almost always a better way.

Comment: you should use margin-left:auto; property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Floats do not work in a flex container

Use `align-self:flex-end` instead

```css
.faq {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.outerDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;

  background-color: yellow;
}

.save {
   align-self:flex-end;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
    <h2>New FAQ</h2>
    <input type="text" class="faq">
    <br>
    <button class="save" mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! align-self: flex-end + margin-right: 25% did it for me :-)

Answer (score 3):

```css
.faq {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.outerDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;

  background-color: yellow;
}

.save {
margin-left:auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
    <h2>New FAQ</h2>
    <input type="text" class="faq">
    <br>
    <button class="save" mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Floats do not work with flex.

There are two approaches that you can take here.

Approach #1:
Use `align-self: flex-end` on the button. This would make the button appear in the rightmost corner of your parent.

Approach #2:
In case you want more control over the position of the button in terms of alignment with the text area, you can wrap the button in a `div` and keep the float right on the button.

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="save" mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button-wrapper {
    width: 50%; /* same as the width of your input*/
}
```